# Instantiate a class in xml android

Tags: android

In my app i am using a class TouchImageView for pinch to zoom. I am instantiating that class from my xml.

```
<com.nspl.utility.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewDoc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

TouchImageView extends ImageView class.

Now, this class get instantiated when setContentView() method is called.
But at a certain point I want to reinstantiate this class. 
How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //What you're code might look like now
        TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewDoc);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.snoopy);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
    }

    //Method to initiate new instance of class
    public TouchImageView newTouchImageView (){
        return new TouchImageView (this); //This constructor should work
    }
}
```

If you want to add the new instance to say a LinearLayout, you could do:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_list);
TouchImageView img = newTouchImageView ();
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.another_image);
img.setMaxZoom(4f);
linearLayout.addView (img);
```

If you want to replace the old view I would simply add the new one and call layoutParent.removeView(oldTouchImageView);